# playing mediaplayer giving outofmeory and vdec open failed

Tags: android

problem with mediaplayer.i pause the mediaplayer in one activity and go another activity and i have to play more videos so i have taken 2 mediaplayers.here the first video is played but the second video is not giving "outofmemory".vdec open failed.can any one solve this one.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you save your video position of the media player in activity #1 and release it in the first place? It definitely is a good idea to call [`MediaPlayer.release()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#release%28%29) to free the resources. And in your scenario I think it is even more important.

Comment: hi mreichelt.gd mrg.actually i am cureently doing what you are suggested.but we need the player in pause mode at first activity.It is working fine in droid phone.but not in Nexus one.we release the first mediaplayer in first activity and when come back from second activity we again starting the player where it stopped.My doubt is why it is working in droidX and why it is not in Nexus one.pls review it again.

Comment: Hmm, I guess I can not say anything without reviewing some code. But if you implement it the "right" way, which means to create & prepare the video in the onResume() method and to release and set it to null in the onPause() method (while saving the playback status first) it should work.¹ (¹ Yes, I know that some phones might behave incorrectly here because some may have different video playback systems. That's a good reason to test this feature as good as you can...)

Comment: hi mreichelt.gd mrg.actually as i already told u in my first activity say A i play a video .when we click on screen it shd display another activity B which contains menu options on left side vertically.Here the "B" is transclent activity.so the paused video frame can be visible to user even in the B activity.Bcoz of the problem we got in NexusOne(but not DroidX) i stoped the video , store the player position and i capture a frame corresponding to that position .I place that frame on the screen.So my requirment is satisfied whith this.but i am not happy with this code.i feel that sth cn be don.